# How do I write data to pandas as columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

I'm struggling to write list into a CSV file.
So first of all i convert list to pandas dataframe and now truing to save it as columns to a file, but data is being displayed from new line.
Can you please help me figure out what I've missing in my code

```
lst = ['Name', 'Age', 'City']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Expected result: `Name, Age, City`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save as columns, assign your list *as columns*:

```
lst = ['Name', 'Age', 'City']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=lst)

df.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

If not specified, the first argument to [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) is `data`, so you must assign to `columns` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd just have to add a `.T` to your line to write the transposed dataframe.

```
df.T.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
---^
```

although if you are using pandas only to write lists as rows to csv files, you'd better have a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, because creating intermediary dataframes is pretty pointless.

```
import csv
lst = ['Name', 'Age', 'City']
with open('file.csv', 'a') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerow(lst)
```